# Como pegar o valor de um campo da tabela do Banco de Dados e usa-lo em uma variável PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Estou com a seguinte dúvida: tenho uma condição `if` `else` em `php` o problema é que necessito de um valor inserido em um campo na tabela do banco de dados para o `script` realizar a condição de `if` ou de `else`.

Minha pergunta é como posso pegar esse valor do banco e passar para a variável que será usada na condição de `if` `else`. Segue abaixo meu código, neste caso preciso que a variável "clique" receba o valor do campo da tabela do banco de dados.

```
$clique=?????????

if($clique == 1){
    echo ("<script>alert('ATENÇÃO: Esse registro já foi constado como entregue e não poderá ser inserido novamente!'); location.href = '../../emprestimo.php';</script>");
}
else
{
$query = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO memprestimo (idemprestimo, movimento, iditem, nomealuno, email, quantidade) SELECT idemprestimo, 'Emprestimo', iditem, nomealuno, email, quantidade FROM emprestimo WHERE idemprestimo = :idemprestimo");
$query->bindParam(':idemprestimo', $idemprestimo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$res = $query->execute();            
unset($query);

$query2 = $conexao->prepare("UPDATE emprestimo SET clique=1 WHERE idemprestimo = :idemprestimo");  
$query2->bindParam(':idemprestimo', $idemprestimo, PDO::PARAM_INT);          
$res2 = $query2->execute();
unset($query2);
echo ("<script>alert('Entrega constada com sucesso!'); location.href = '../../emprestimo.php';</script>");
}
```

Comment: Pegue o valor no banco e coloque no $clique, tipo: `$clique = row['coluna'];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que você poderá criar uma consulta para recuperar esse dado da tabela do banco do mesmo jeito que faz para inserir ou atualizar os registros. Desse modo:

```
$select = $conexao->prepare("SELECT clique FROM tabela WHERE condicao");
$select->execute();
$clique = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

No caso, o `clique` seria o campo da tabela o qual você quer recuperar o dado, a `tabela` de onde você quer recuperar e a `condicao` se existir alguma, se não existir apenas ignore o `where`.

Comment: Olá tentei da sua forma mas acaba que sempre executa apenas a condição else, mesmo essa condição atualizando o valor do banco pra 1 ela continua entrando no else sem considerar o valor atualizado do banco

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa tarde amigo!

Primeiro você deve declarar a sua variável no topo do código:

```
$clique = "";
```

Depois realize a sua consulta:

```
$query = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO memprestimo (idemprestimo, movimento, iditem, nomealuno, email, quantidade) SELECT idemprestimo, 'Emprestimo', iditem, nomealuno, email, quantidade FROM emprestimo WHERE idemprestimo = :idemprestimo");
$query->bindParam(':idemprestimo', $idemprestimo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$res = $query->execute();            

$query2 = $conexao->prepare("UPDATE emprestimo SET clique=1 WHERE idemprestimo = :idemprestimo");  
$query2->bindParam(':idemprestimo', $idemprestimo, PDO::PARAM_INT);          
$res2 = $query2->execute();
```

Verifique se as duas `queries` do seu código `mysql` foram atendidas corretamente:

```
if($query && $query2){
    echo ("<script>alert('Entrega constada com sucesso!'); location.href = '../../emprestimo.php';</script>");  
}else{
    $clique = 1;
}
```

Se a consulta `mysql` não for atendida, o valor de `$clique` será alterado para o valor 1, assim executando:

```
if($clique == 1){
    echo ("<script>alert('ATENÇÃO: Esse registro já foi constado como entregue e não poderá ser inserido novamente!'); location.href = '../../emprestimo.php';</script>");
}
```

OBS: Eu não testei o código.

Comment: Olá, o problema é que essas duas queries minhas só podem ser executadas 1 vez. Por q primeiro é realizado um insert na tabela emprestimo e nela o valor do clique é iniciado com 0, ai entra nessas duas queries do código onde na primeira querie eu replico os dados da tabela emprestimo para a tabela memprestimo e a segunda query muda o valor do clique pra 1, ai ele teria q executar a segunda condição q é quando o clique está com o valor 1, seria basicamente pra impedir q o usuario insara duas vezes a mesma coisa da tabela emprestimo na tabela memprestimo

Answer (score 0):

Tente executar uma nova consulta com base no `idemprestimo` para trazer as informações de clique, exemplo:

```
SELECT clique FROM emprestimo WHERE idemprestimo = :idemprestimo
```

Feito isso atribua o valor trazido do banco à variável `$clique`.